# Combine multiple videos on panels that move around?

Tags: animation, video, audio

I'm making a music video with multiple panels, where each panel displays the video of a different instrument (bass, guitar, voice, etc.) playing the song. I need to animate the panels so they move about, and will also include stills for the background.

The videos have an alpha channel (they were taken in front of a green screen, which I'm keying out). The background should show through where the videos are transparent.

All the videos need to be perfectly synchronized with each other and the sound track.

What's the best approach to achieve this? From what I've read so far, I imagine it'd be to animate the panels and the background (as a 2d animation) and add the videos as textures on the panels. Is that right?

Also, is Blender the best FOSS tool for the job? (I'm using only FOSS.)

Many thanks in advance!!

Comment: In my  opinion the best approach for a project like this is using a proper video editing program. Blender's VSE is quite limited and not the most flexible or responsive.... try Resolve, (free, but not open source).

Comment: You could build a simple 3D scene, set up a bunch of simple plane objects with the required videos as textures, overlayed on top of each other, animate it and add an orthographic camera on top.  Render using the quick viewport OpenGL only.

Comment: Thanks!!! Yes, @DuarteFarrajotaRamos, that's about what I was imagining, but I'm pretty new to Blender...

Comment: Thanks, @cegaton... My hesitation about video editors is that they'll be lacking on the animation side of things. Maybe I'm wrong about that?

Comment: I think that Blender would be ideal for this project. The sound is already mixed and consists of only 1 track. You just need to place it on the VSE timeline and set markers at different sue points. These markers will be available in the timeline toolbar as well. Apply textures to planes with transparent shader applied to alpha. Consider your camera placement first then animate each instrument or plane, in a complete pass.